# How to override resource models?

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides, resource-model

I wanted to overrid:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Compare/Item/Collection.php
```

so I copied it to:

```
app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Compare/Item/Collection.php
```

But the override is not working.

Please let me know how I can override it without creating a new module.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work. I can't imagine any way to do it without the custom module, there are several clean ways, though, depending what you exactly want. Most wanted is using `plugin` pattern:
[Plugins docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Another manner is using `observer` pattern if the feature you want to rewrite dispatches some events. More: 
[Observer docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html)

Finally, if neither `plugins`  nor `observers` suits your case you can use `preference`, which helps you to replace whole class. More:
[Preference tutorial](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_preferences/)

Comment: Thank you. You are right, cannot be done without custom module. I created custom module and used "preferences" method.